# How to scroll UITableView cell out of the way of the on-screen keyboad?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

This must be a common problem... I have a `UITextField` inside of a table cell, and I want to let the user edit it. However when the keyboard appears, it often obscures the text field.

I've tried using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition`, but surprisingly this does not work. I've tried setting `UITableViewScrollPosition` to `{None,Top,Button,Middle}` .

What's the secret to scrolling that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The secret is that you've got to manually implement the behavior and it's a pain.

There's a few steps you've got to take:

**Step 1: Register for keyboard notifications**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}
```

**Step 2: Resize the content inset when the keyboard appears**

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, kbSize.height, 0.0f);
    self.tableview.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.selectedView.frame animated:YES];
}
```

This assumes that you've got a property in your class called "selectedView". There's other ways to do this, but the main thing is that somehow you need to know what view rect the user needs to see.

**Step 3: Reset your table view when the keyboard disappears**

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tableview.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

**Step 4: Unregister for notifications**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do something similar without notifications and it wasn't working of course. Now it does.

Comment: @Starboo Don't use hardcoded values, it will almost certainly break in future iOS releases. If your text area is flying off the screen, it's probably because you aren't setting the `selectedView` correctly, but without more code that's just a guess.

Answer (score -1):

So, does your table cell hiding your textfield right? Why do you want to solve it with scrolling? Change the way of adding your textfield to your cell.

Comment: His question is how to avoid having a textfield hidden by a keyboard